# How do I set a custom cursor theme in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, customization, cursor

I would just like to set a custom cursor theme on my computer. I had this pack back on 10.10 from here. http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=50663. But I can't seem to recall how I did it. I've tried just about everything. I've installed the Gnome Tweak Tool and tried to set it, now it works only a little bit here and there. (Certain parts of certain windows.) If I finish through the terminal (sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme) It doesn't even come up as an option. Even though it's been manually inserted into usr/share/icons. Is there anyone that can help me get this cursor pack working? It would be even greater if this pack can be converted for linux use. http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-set/legend-of-zelda.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using two tools, `ubuntu-tweak` and `gnome-tweak-tool`. But if you say it works sometimes and doesn't sometimes, then I think your problem is with your cursor theme, not with how to activate it.